# Pygal: Displaying information for each data point

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, pygal

I have been playing around with `Pygal`, creating some line graphs for a project I am working on. I currently have my `y axis` set to be the value recorded and the `x axis` being the `date / time` the test was conducted. However I would also like to link the serial number to each data point. At the moment when you hover on a data point you get the y value in bold and underneith that you get the date it was recorded.

Does anyone know if it is possible to link information to data points without them being an axis label?

For reference I currently have the serial numbers being added to the `list: 'sn_list'`.

```
        for row in line_graph_query:
            if str(row.date_time) >= start_date and str(row.date_time) <= end_date :
                min_values.append(float(row.minimum_value))
                max_values.append(float(row.maximum_value))
                recorded_values.append(float(row.recorded_value))
                sn_list.append(row.product_serial_number)
                date_list.append(row.date_time)
                number_of_records = number_of_records + 1
        print(min_values)
        print(max_values)
        print(recorded_values)
        distance_x_axis = math.floor(number_of_records/6)
        line_chart = pygal.Line(no_data_text='No result found', style=custom_style,x_labels_major_every=distance_x_axis, x_label_rotation=20, show_minor_x_labels=False )
        line_chart.title = 'Detailed Results of '+test_name+' tests of '+board_pn
        line_chart.x_labels = map(str,date_list)
        line_chart.add('Minimum', min_values)
        line_chart.add('Maximum', max_values)
        line_chart.add('Recorded', recorded_values)
        graph_render.append(line_chart.render_data_uri())
        graphs_to_render[test_name] = graph_render[-1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the tooltip to any text you like by providing your data as dicts ([see the documentation here](http://pygal.org/en/stable/documentation/configuration/value.html#labels)).  Each value should be represented by a `dict` that has at least a `value` attribute, this is the same value that you were providing to the chart directly.  There are then a number of other attributes you can set, amongst them `label`.

You should be able to get the tooltips you want by changing the three lines that append data in your `if` structure:

```
min_values.append({"value": float(row.minimum_value),
                   "label": row.product_serial_number})
max_values.append({"value": float(row.maximum_value),
                   "label": row.product_serial_number})
recorded_values.append({"value": float(row.recorded_value),
                        "label": row.product_serial_number})
```

Unless you are using it somewhere else this also means that you have no need of the `sn_list`.

Comment: Thank you, was trying to figure this out the other day, I had just been trying to generate the dict in the wrong place. Worked perfectly.